# How to insert one character before another?

Tags: javascript, jquery, string, insert, character

I have a list with the following markup:

```
<ul class="meta meta-event">
    <li>September 4 @ 10:00 am - 5:00 pm</li>
    <li>Some Hotel, London</li>
</ul>
```

But I'd like to insert a `<br />` tag before the '@' character (I need to do this in jQuery due to it being a WP plugin with little customisation optons)

Does anyone know how I can do it?

Comment: `$('.meta-event li:contains("@")').html(function(i,html){ return html.replace(/@/, '<br />@') })`

Comment: is it always the same li the first li?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use jQuery's [`html()`](http://api.jquery.com/html/) method, and a string replace to insert the `<br>` tag before the `@`

```
$('.meta-event li:contains(@)').html(function(_, html) {
    return html.replace(/@/g, '<br />@');
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/kprxsjo4/)